# Strange behavior with string literals in C kernel

Tags: c, kernel, string-literals

I am relatively new to C, I admit, but I thought I understood the concepts pretty well. Despite this, I am noticing some odd behavior with string literals, that my google searching seems to indicate it shouldn't be happening. Is there something important I am missing, or is this an indication of some underlying problem in my kernel? When running this code:

```
debug_print("Directly in parameter.");

char test1[] = "With array.";
debug_print(test1);

char* test2 = "With pointer.";
debug_print(test2);

char test3[] = "With array, then pointer.";
char* test3_1 = &test3[0];
debug_print(test3_1);

char* test4 = "With pointer, then malloc.";
char* test4_1 = malloc(27);
memory_copy(test4, test4_1, 27);
debug_print(test4_1);

char test5[] = "With array, then malloc.";
char* test5_1 = malloc(25);
memory_copy(test5, test5_1, 25);
debug_print(test5_1);
```

(debug_print takes a const char* as a parameter, and prints it to serial0. memory_copy copies memory from the first parameter to the second, of the length specified in the third parameter. The malloc function is also custom, but I have done extensive testing to ensure it works fine.)

I get this output:

```
                               <-- There is a null string here...
With array.
                               <-- There is a null string here...
With array, then pointer.
                               <-- There is a null string here...
With array, then malloc.
```

It would seem that the string literal is apparently ignored if it is not initially stored as a char array. Why could this be? In case it is helpful, I am compiling with gcc with these args:

```
-ffreestanding -g -std=c99 -m32 -masm=intel -Wall
```

EDIT: As requested, here is my debug_print code:

```
void debug_print(const char* message) {
    for (int i = 0;message[i] != 0;i++) port_byte_out(0x3F8, message[i]);
    port_byte_out(0x3F8, '\r');
    port_byte_out(0x3F8, '\n');
}
```

and for good measure, here's memory_copy, since I didn't realize it was similar to a standard c function.

```
void memory_copy(const char* source, char* dest, int no_bytes) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < no_bytes; i++) {
        *(dest + i) = *(source + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second parameter of `memory_copy` is the destination?

Comment: Yes, completely sure. I have used it on other places, and it works fine then (cases not involving string literals).

Comment: Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior. No since in trying to make sense of what you see after you do that.. it may seg fault, it may not, it may restart as a Windows 10 box.. undefined behavior is undefined, not guaranteed to crash.

Comment: You have the first `debug_print()`  call which works in unexpected manner (prints nothing). Why do you provide other code? Instead, provide implementation of `debug_print` function.

Comment: Nowhere am I modifying a string literal. I don't see why you all seem to think I am...

Comment: Can you provide the code of `debug_print()`?

Comment: @SuperKael Probably because the parameters of `memory_copy` are swapped wrt. the standard function `memcpy`.

Comment: The `memcpy` function has the destination as the first parameter and the source as the second.  Your function switches them.

Comment: Maybe add `\n` to the strings so debug print will flush.

Comment: @Angew yes .. SuperKael my apologies, didn't read closely and assumed the destination was first

Comment: I added the code for both debug_print and memory_copy. Hopefully that clears up confusion.

Comment: With `#define port_byte_out(x,c) putchar(c)`, this works as expected in userspace.

Comment: I feared as much. That's why I'm wondering if there might be something fundamentally wrong with my kernel, or if I'm compiling it wrong somehow (that's why I included my gcc arguments.)

Comment: Might be a linker issue. Did you inspect the generated assembler code (-s option)?

Comment: According to the outputted assembly (with the -S option, capitalization matters apparently) I see that it is storing the three string literals that are not working (specifically those ones) directly above the actual function code. It then pushes the data from the labels for each one onto the stack, and calls _debug_print. I don't see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong capitalization.

Comment: Are the symbols still in the executable? What is your executable format? Can you generate a assembler dump (`objdump -D`) and compare it with the generated assembler?

Comment: Is this your kernel for an x86 machine? If yes, have you set all the segments correctly? Are they loaded correctly? If this is a low-level problem, rather than a C issue, then I'd check the segments. The strings missing are those allocated in the data segment (and not copied on the stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm dumb - Thanks to @Matthias for suggesting using objdump. Upon doing so, I realized that the string literals were in a different section than the rest of my code. More specifically, my code is in '.text' while the literals were somewhere else, not sure where exactly. As part of my Makefile, I was doing:

```
objcopy -O binary -j .text $< $@
```

Notice the '-j .text'. I'm not sure why I was doing that exactly, it was trashing the literals! Thanks, and I apologize for my idiocy.